# Tinting ImageView image resource (png) with color state list

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm not getting the same behavior when tinting an `ImageView` button with a **color state list** as I do when using a "**drawable selector**" (that points to a pre-rendered alternate image).

When the button is tapped there is no color change whatsoever, and when held down for a second or two a color change does occur but sometimes only in the bottom half of the icon.

**note:** I'm trying to make just the button change color, not the entire background, so that it appears to glow when touched (without having to pre-color it in an editor).

**note:** I realize these icons are old, and not from the new *material* set, but I can't use those just yet.

**resource/drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar.png**

[image: ic_menu_my_calendar]

**resource/color/calendar_btn_color_state_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#A0AA3355"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#A0AA3355"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#A0AA3355"/>  
  <item android:color="#FFAAAAAA"/>

</selector>
```

**usage**

```
_calendarButton = new ImageButton(this.Context);
_calendarButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_my_calendar);
_calendarButton.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);

var csl = ColorStateList.CreateFromXml(Resources, Resources.GetXml(Resource.Color.calendar_btn_color_state_list));

// all options give the same unexpected behavior
_calendarButton.Drawable.SetTintList(csl);   // option 1
_calendarButton.Background.SetTintList(csl); // option 2
_calendarButton.ImageTintList = csl;         // option 3

// tried a bunch of modes, didn't help
//_calendarButton.ImageTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn;
```

---

**The following gives the behavior I'd like to achieve above.**

**resource/drawable/calendar_btn_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar_pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"/>
</selector>
```

**usage**

```
_calendarButton = new ImageButton(this.Context);
_calendarButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.calendar_btn_selector);
_calendarButton.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

**UPDATE**

Found some cool effects using GIMP for pre-render method

[image]

It was done with layering

[image]